# Нужны часы на javascript

Tags: javascript

Нужен скрипт часов, чтобы в любом часовом поясе показывалось время заданного часового пояса. Например, мне нужно, чтобы на сайте всегда отображалось московское время.

Comment: http://momentjs.com/

Comment: скрипты нужно не доставать, а учиться писать.

Answer (score 4):

А в чем трудность? По словам javascript clock в Google сразу находятся:

- [Creating a JavaScript Clock](http://www.elated.com/articles/creating-a-javascript-clock/)
- [The Javascript Analog Clock](http://randomibis.com/coolclock/)